# Finding a quiet place to meet in San Francisco (or any city)?

Tags: accommodation, cities, san-francisco

I am going to a conference in San Francisco, and would like to schedule a one hour meeting with two people in person and one on Skype, somewhere near the Moscone center.

What are my options for conducting such a meeting privately? Is this a service that I could ask a hotel or meeting staff to provide? Are there places that rent a room for an hour?

Comment: If you're going to a *conference*, my first thought would be to ask the conference venue.

Comment: @masta good lead, the conference center redirected me to the meeting organizer, who has no more rooms and redirected me to a hotel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost all major hotels will do this. Conference centres will also make rooms available, especially if you are a conference attendee.

The Moscone Center can provide these - they can also provide connection services if you also wanted to Skype from the room as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can rent a conference room from a company like [Regus](http://www.regus.com). They have many locations in [San Francisco](http://www.regus.com/business-centre/san-francisco).